# Error in fetching repositories for ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS using do-release-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, updates, 20.04, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I tried to update my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` on my command line and it worked fine for a while, where it downloaded some repositories. After a while, it showed the following error:

```
Fetching
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0134+dfsg-1build1 [320 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0134+dfsg-1build1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Hashes of expected file:
 - SHA256:02d4e0d785142836422d6ad32c7db158008bdc2b2975fd971e55476645b2ccb8
 - SHA1:18b39e848e301bb2f8ccc36c602426fd73ca9d64 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:8af41e9004d000b38f5b7e3f54117a61 [weak]
 - Filesize:319596 [weak]
Hashes of received file:
 - SHA256:df3a205735aa739038c3cc258ad97b45b50db29ad0efea9d03a6a6702f8cafda
 - SHA1:055d12a01dc616d56258cf3fb0f6e8d2af693d12 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:1e9b487c5b050c7818cdf9bdb65c95dc [weak]
 - Filesize:319596 [weak]
Last modification reported: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 21:47:31 +0000

Fetched 320 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0134+dfsg-1build1 [320 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0134+dfsg-1build1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Hashes of expected file:
 - SHA256:02d4e0d785142836422d6ad32c7db158008bdc2b2975fd971e55476645b2ccb8
 - SHA1:18b39e848e301bb2f8ccc36c602426fd73ca9d64 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:8af41e9004d000b38f5b7e3f54117a61 [weak]
 - Filesize:319596 [weak]
Hashes of received file:
 - SHA256:df3a205735aa739038c3cc258ad97b45b50db29ad0efea9d03a6a6702f8cafda
 - SHA1:055d12a01dc616d56258cf3fb0f6e8d2af693d12 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:1e9b487c5b050c7818cdf9bdb65c95dc [weak]
 - Filesize:319596 [weak]
Last modification reported: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 21:47:31 +0000

Fetched 320 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0134+dfsg-1build1 [320 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0134+dfsg-1build1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Hashes of expected file:
 - SHA256:02d4e0d785142836422d6ad32c7db158008bdc2b2975fd971e55476645b2ccb8
 - SHA1:18b39e848e301bb2f8ccc36c602426fd73ca9d64 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:8af41e9004d000b38f5b7e3f54117a61 [weak]
 - Filesize:319596 [weak]
Hashes of received file:
 - SHA256:df3a205735aa739038c3cc258ad97b45b50db29ad0efea9d03a6a6702f8cafda
 - SHA1:055d12a01dc616d56258cf3fb0f6e8d2af693d12 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:1e9b487c5b050c7818cdf9bdb65c95dc [weak]
 - Filesize:319596 [weak]
Last modification reported: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 21:47:31 +0000

Fetched 320 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   

Could not download the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have 
been kept. 

Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml-libxml-perl/libxml-libxml-perl_2.0134+dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb 
Hash Sum mismatch 
Hashes of expected file: 
- 
SHA256:02d4e0d785142836422d6ad32c7db158008bdc2b2975fd971e55476645b2ccb8 
- SHA1:18b39e848e301bb2f8ccc36c602426fd73ca9d64 [weak] 
- MD5Sum:8af41e9004d000b38f5b7e3f54117a61 [weak] 
- Filesize:319596 [weak] 
Hashes of received file: 
- 
SHA256:df3a205735aa739038c3cc258ad97b45b50db29ad0efea9d03a6a6702f8cafda 
- SHA1:055d12a01dc616d56258cf3fb0f6e8d2af693d12 [weak] 
- MD5Sum:1e9b487c5b050c7818cdf9bdb65c95dc [weak] 
- Filesize:319596 [weak] 
Last modification reported: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 21:47:31 +0000 




Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

I tried the whole process of `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` again and it showed the same error. How to overcome this error to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04?

Please help!